# WebStorm remote debug shows different file content

Tags: node.js, webstorm

I'm using WebStorm 2018.2 on Windows 10.
When trying the debug remotely instead of using the file already open in the editor it opens a new file. usually it's identical to the local file but I can't create breakpoint. If I want to do so I need to set a breakpoint on the local file, then the code will stop at the remote server and remote file.
This is very annoying but manageable.

The problem is that a decent amount of times it opens a new file with the same name as it should but the content of the file is completely different. so I can't really see what part of the code I'm at.

I see from coworkers that for them it shows the remote debug on the local files.
How can it be fixed?

Thanks you.

Answer (score 0):

Arte you using  **Attach to Node.js/Chrome** run configuration to attach to remote process?
In WebStorm 2018.2, remote URL mappings don't work as expected there, [WEB-34204](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-34204) is fixed in 2018.3.x. Please try upgrading WebStorm